# iOS App Commenting Truncates Last Character

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

I wish I could reliably reproduce this. It's frequent, but not every single time. Maybe about 50%.

When posting a comment through the iOS App, the last character of a comment I post is often truncated. The contents of the comment do not appear to have an impact.

So if I were to type

> Great answer! +1

it would show up as

> Great answer! +

<sub>(comment text used for demonstration purposes only. My comments are of course only ever of the *highest* standards of excellence.</sub>

---

I'll comment on this post repeatedly with different potential steps to reproduce, ending each with a **X**

**Edit:** it happened when I switched to the Answers tab before tapping send

Comment: Adding a normal comment. X

Comment: Adding comment, then backspace at end X

Comment: Typing, sleep, wake, send X

Comment: Type, switch to answers tab then 
back

Comment: HA! there it is!

Comment: Type, switch to Answers, switch back, then type more X

Comment: Type, scroll, send X

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful (detailed) bug report, I'll take a look at this immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in version **0.1.22**. The bug happened when submitting a comment while the text cursor was not at the end of the comment – this was causing some submission logic, which removed the newline character at the end of the line, to truncate the last character.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so muc

Comment: Testing comment in 0.1.22

Comment: Great! Fixed! Thank you